# How to get a value from database on Laravel Controller?

Tags: laravel, api, eloquent

I have this code where I want to select certain values from the table. Counter is my Model.

```
$today = '2022-03-16';
$tanggal = Counter::select('tanggal')->where('api', 'Agenda')->where('tanggal', $today)->get();
```

But if i `dd($tanggal->tanggal)`, it returns with an error `Property [tanggal] does not exist on this collection instance.`

How to get a value from 'tanggal' attribute?

Comment: `get()` returns a collection. A collection is an array of objects. So you need to loop through that array to access individual instances. I suppose what you should be using here is `first()` instead of `get()` but that is if you are expecting only one record. Otherwise, yeah. loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are using get() method. it will return collection. You can not access any field directly from collection.
You have to need use **freach** loop to access single property.

```
$today = '2022-03-16';
$tanggals = Counter::select('tanggal')
    ->where('api', 'Agenda')->where('tanggal', $today)->get();
forech( $tanggals as  $tanggal)
{
    dump($tanggal->tanggal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a model property from a `Collection`, this can be fixed like so:

```php
$tanggal = Counter::where(['api' => 'Agenda', 'tanggal' => $today])->first(['tanggal']);
```

`get()` returns a Collection, `first()` returns a `Model`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the collection but then use its .each() method and give it a lambda instead to process each value.

```
$collection = Counter::select('tanggal')->where('api', 'Agenda')->where('tanggal', $today)->get();
$collection->each(function ($item, $key) { 
    //write now your code here  can do $item->tanggal

});
```